# How to convert double to date in jooq

Tags: datetime, type-conversion, timestamp, double, jooq

```
Select TIMESTAMP 'epoch' 
+ INTERVAL '1 second' * round(extract('epoch' from date) / :'agginterval') * 'agginterval' as date,    ROUND(AVG(data)) AS data 
FROM  my_data 
WHERE'startDate' <= date    
  AND date <= 'endDate' GROUP BY 1
```

I want this sql statement in jooq but timestamp epoch and interval is not be done how i convert double to interval by multiply and add to timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

As of jOOQ 3.12, jOOQ's `INTERVAL` type support is probably insufficient to implement the expression you're looking for using the DSL API.

As a workaround, you can resort to using the [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) API to enhance jOOQ functionality